# Android Array list save and recall best method

Tags: android, arrays, list

I have a list(3 list) which comprises of

1. Name, Telephone, Code
2. want to save the array recall and select even after the app is closed.
3. The Code so far, which creates the list.

   ```
   final EditText et=(EditText)findViewById    (R.id.telephone_number_reference_entry);
   final EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.telephone_number_entry);
   final EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.access_code_entry);
   final ListView new_text_number=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_text_number);
   final ListView  telephone_number_reference=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.telephone_number_reference);
   final ListView  access_code_reference=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.access_code_reference);

   final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
   aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
   new_text_number.setAdapter(aa);

   final ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   final ArrayAdapter<String> aa2;
   aa2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list2);
   telephone_number_reference.setAdapter(aa2);

   final ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
   final ArrayAdapter<String> aa3;
   aa3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list3);
   access_code_reference.setAdapter(aa3);


   add_number_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           if(et.getText().length()>0 && et.getText().length()>0 && et2.getText().length()>3 && et2.getText().length()<=7) {

               list.add(0,et.getText().toString());
               aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
               et.setText("");
               list2.add(0,et1.getText().toString());
               aa2.notifyDataSetChanged();
               et1.setText("");
               list3.add(0,et2.getText().toString());
               aa3.notifyDataSetChanged();
               et2.setText("");       }

       }
   });
   ```

appreciate any help been going round in circles on this one, I current save other data as shared pref

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Settings_Pref, 0);
```

This works fine, in that change them and can recall them , but need to do the list, all the list is data to be recalled and used for different sms systems but rather than remember all the different systems and manually type it in, want to be able to recall.

Not sure I am looking at this the right way, any help tinyDB option maybe greatly received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data by using **[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)**:

If you use Android Studio, you need to add the following dependency to your app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
}
```

Saving an ArrayList:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();

String json = gson.toJson(arrayList);

editor.putString(YOUR_PREFERENCE_KEY, json);
editor.commit();
```

To read the ArrayList (remember that you need to add `import java.lang.reflect.Type`):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = sharedPrefs.getString(YOUR_PREFERENCE_KEY, null);
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayObject>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<ArrayObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way, looks like in intellj I need to add gradle or import a gradle project never used it previously and doesn't look straight forward to integrate?

Comment: oww.. never try with intelliJ. Perhaps this should help you: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html

Comment: Really struggling to add gradle to dependencies, at least  can see gradle I have an android and a java gradle available but cant seem to be able to get either in the dependencies tab.....

Comment: is there any build.gradle file in your IntelliJ project?

Comment: I can if I set up a new project and select gradle upfront, so need to import and merge or something I guess, at least I am getting somewhere now

Comment: I never thought that it takes much work to adding a dependency. I always thought that an Android project in IntelliJ is the same with Android Studio. I feel sorry for you :(

Comment: lol its probably me making it more difficult than it should be.

Comment: Wish you the best ;)

Comment: well managed to get gradle added  in the dependencies what a farce, followed this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-a-gradle-project.html but not exactly as its written.  Now just have to work on getting it to work.